# Python subprocess with complex arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm looking for the safest and most convenient way to call a shell command from python(3). Here a ps to pdf conversion:

```
 gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="${pdf_file}" "${ps_file}"
```

I use `subprocess`, `shlex` and avoid `shell=True`.
But I find the resulting command inconsistent:

```
cmd = ['gs', '-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-sOutputFile={0}'.format(pdf_filename), ps_filename]
```

What do I miss?! `subprocess.call()` syntax looks so clean with space separated arguments, and looks such a mess everywhere else.

What's the difference when calling `subprocess.call(cmd)` (at python level, ie. escaping, injection protection, quoting, etc.) between:

```
cmd = ['do', '--something', arg]
cmd = ['do', '--someting {0}'.format(arg)]
```

If none, is this, also, a good way to do it ?

```
cmd = ['gs', '-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile={0} {1}'.format(pdf_filename, ps_filename)]
```

Another example of inconsistency:

`hg merge -r 3` would be `cmd = ['hg', 'merge', '-r', revision_id]`

`hg merge --rev=3` would be `cmd = ['hg', 'merge', '--rev={0}'.format(revision_id)]`

despite the fact, it is two ways to send the same arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the command may have a `--something` option which accepts an argument, but it doesn't have a `--something foo` option -- which is what you would be telling it. When you run a command in your shell, like `wc -l myfile.txt`, your shell splits up that commandline where it finds spaces -- so the command that gets run is `['wc', '-l', 'myfile.txt']`.

The `subprocess` module does not perform such splitting. You have to do it yourself (unless you use the 'shell' option, but that's generally less secure, so avoid it if you can.).

Some anti-examples...

Try to run a command named "wc -l myfile.txt". Of course, there is no "wc -l myfile.txt" command installed, only a "wc" command, so this will fail:

```
['wc -l myfile.txt']
```

Try to run a command "wc" with an option "-l myfile.txt". There is an "-l" option, but no "-l myfile.txt" option. This will fail:

```
['wc', '-l myfile.txt']
```

and a correct example:

```
['wc', '-l', 'myfile.txt']
```

This calls wc with the `-l` option (print only the line count) and `myfile.txt` as the only filename.

Something you may have found confusing is fragments like this:

`'-sOutputFile={0}'`

This is an 'inline' style of giving the argument of an option. If this is supported, the help for the program usually says so explicitly. Python does not split these -- the program receiving them does.

There are three main styles of 'inline' arguments. I'll use `grep` options to demo the first two:

```
--context=3
-C3
```

(the above two lines are equivalent)

The third type is only found in imagemagick and a few other programs that tend to have reams of commandline arguments, such as gs:

```
-sOutputFile=foo
```

This is just a minor variation on the GNU standard --long-option=VALUE form shown above.

[The GNU libc manual's "argument syntax" section](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) gives a full explanation of these option passing conventions.

- In regards to escaping: No escaping is done, and no escaping is normally needed. The string values are passed *exactly as you specify* to the command. Naturally, no quoting is done nor is it needed, since you already took care of that in your Python code.
- In regards to injection: this is not possible unless you use the 'shell' option. **Don't use the 'shell' option** :).

Comment: This sounds fine... But options with a `=` sign or no space, or an optionnal `=` seems to be all special cases. Shouldn't an argument be always in its own list item ? (cf. appended example)

Comment: They are special cases -- for the program that receives them. Python does nothing special with them, the program - for example `gs` or `hg` - just accepts them in that format. My latest edit hopefully explains in full. BTW, you don't have to use ['--rev=3'] -- you can also use the non-inline form, ['--rev','3'] (thus avoiding using `format()`)

Comment: thanks for the edit! Still dreaming of a perfectly uniform way to pass arguments in shell, not touchy about spaces... (alas it's off topic :))

Comment: `shell` is not deprecated. It is just often unnecessary and if the command arguments come from untrusted sources then it can be unsafe. Also, `subprocess` module always passes the command as a string on Windows.

Comment: Or, in other words: `shell` plays in one league with `exec`/`eval` or `goto` in other languages: they are not bad per se, but they are bad if you don't think about before using them and only use  them if necessary and appropriate.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for that clarification, I've updated my answer accordingly. I think what I was thinking of when I decided it must be deprecated, was a recommendation when porting from `os.popen` to `subprocess`, to not use 'shell'.

Answer (score 2):

Difference between what you asked.. easy to check:

```
arg = 'foo'

cmd = ['do', '--something', arg]
print cmd
cmd = ['do', '--someting {0}'.format(arg)]
print cmd

>>> 
['do', '--something', 'foo']
['do', '--someting foo']
```

As you can see they are not the same.

In order to call your subprocess correctly, you should do this:

```
cmd = ['gs', '-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-sOutputFile={0}'.format(pdf_filename), ps_filename]
subprocess.Popen(cmd, ...)
```

OR:

```
cmd = 'gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile={0} {1}'.format(pdf_filename, ps_filename)
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, ...)
```

---

The difference between using a list of arguments or a string:

When you use a list of arguments, you are passing those as the arguments to the shell (or executable if you specify)

And when you send a string with `shell=True` you let the shell parse the string and make its own arguments...

So `['do', '--something', 'foo']` is 3 arguments, while `['do', '--someting foo']` is only 2 arguments.

Comment: I agree with the first part, my question was about the difference when passed to subprocess.call(). I edit the question accordingly. Thx